# Testing reliability of a 4G connection: how to get full and accurate PING logging?

Tags: windows-7, networking, ping, logging

I have a SIM card on a smartphone; my carrier provided me a public IP (which I binded to a fixed hostname by using the noip service).
I'm doing some tests about the reliability of this 4G connection (which is also related to the phone itself,  when it enters in deep sleep mode).
I'm currently using `cryping` on Windows 7, I'm running the following command in a command prompt window:

```
cryping -d -p 12345 -r 60 -t $HOSTNAME
```

I continuosly ping the IP every 60 seconds; thanks to the `-d` *flag* I also get a timestamp, but only when the command finds the host reachable.
Currently, in the command prompt I get:

> ```
> C:\CRYPING>cryping -d -p 12345 -r 60 -t $HOSTNAME
> 17-11-14 17:28:34 Successful connection to $HOSTNAME port=12345 time=9,2s
> Failed to connect to $HOSTNAME, port 12345
> Failed to connect to $HOSTNAME, port 12345
> Failed to connect to $HOSTNAME, port 12345
> Failed to connect to $HOSTNAME, port 12345
> Failed to connect to $HOSTNAME, port 12345
> Failed to connect to $HOSTNAME, port 12345
> Failed to connect to $HOSTNAME, port 12345
> 17-11-14 17:39:02 Successful connection to $HOSTNAME port=12345 time=172ms
> ```

Since 17:28 to 17:39, are passed 11 minutes, but the "Failed to connect" message has been displayed only seven times.

**What I aim to achieve:**

I'd want the timestamp also when the host is unreachable, and furthermore, logging the whole output to a text file, so something like:

> ```
> 17-11-14 17:28:34 Successful connection to $HOSTNAME port=12345 time=9,2s
> 17-11-14 17:29:34 Failed to connect to $HOSTNAME, port 12345
> 17-11-14 17:30:34 Failed to connect to $HOSTNAME, port 12345
> 17-11-14 17:31:34 Failed to connect to $HOSTNAME, port 12345
> 17-11-14 17:32:34 Failed to connect to $HOSTNAME, port 12345
> 17-11-14 17:33:34 Failed to connect to $HOSTNAME, port 12345
> 17-11-14 17:34:34 Failed to connect to $HOSTNAME, port 12345
> 17-11-14 17:35:34 Failed to connect to $HOSTNAME, port 12345
> 17-11-14 17:36:34 Failed to connect to $HOSTNAME, port 12345
> 17-11-14 17:37:34 Failed to connect to $HOSTNAME, port 12345
> 17-11-14 17:38:34 Failed to connect to $HOSTNAME, port 12345
> 17-11-14 17:39:34 Failed to connect to $HOSTNAME, port 12345
> 17-11-14 17:39:02 Successful connection to $HOSTNAME port=12345 time=172ms
> ```

I suspect that the first issue (the timestamp also when the host is unreachable) is a limit of `cryping`? Considering that I am on Windows 7, there is something better than `cryping`? I'd also want to save the output to a text file, but in the meantime (while saving the log to a text file) the command prompt must continue to shows the output of `cryping`.
Please keep also in mind that I have to ping a specific port on my host.

Comment: The timestamp is when a reply gets back to your host. If the target does not respond, there is no reply, so there is no timestamp.

Comment: @RonMaupin ok, but I need to get timestamp also when the target does not respond, and according to the cyclic time.

Comment: What timestamp? If you don't get a response, there is no timestamp. You would be comparing apples (the time when you get a response) to oranges (some random time). If you do this, the timestamp is meaningless.

Comment: research and logging purposes; I've done some research about something similar; some people relies to these commands:
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==1 ECHO %DATE% %TIME% Fail>>C:\log.txt

Comment: Any timestamps on non-replies simply cannot be compared to timestamps on replies. They would be completely different things. Any research that compares them would be invalid. If you had timestamps from when the requests were sent, then you could compare them because they would be the same thing, but the timestamps you have simply don't exist for the non-replies. It's like timing in a race: you want to compare the times of people cross the finish line to the times of people who never finish the race. People who never finish the race have no times.

Comment: My carrier asked me to log almost everything; doesn't matter if the timestamp when the host is unreachable is not perfectly accurate. As you can read on my question, cryping also doesn't follow the timeout (-r flag) when the host is unreachable: I just want to also records this.

Comment: I guess you really just don't understand. What you are asking for doesn't exist. What timestamp would you record for a person who doesn't finish a race? If you never receive a reply, you cannot record when you received the reply. You want to document something that doesn't exist.